# How do we authenticate against a secured NuGet server with Cake build?

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget, build-server, cakebuild

We are working on automating our builds using Cake Build and we use NuGet packages from nuget.org but we also have our own NuGet Feed server which has a username/password authentication to access.  How do we utilize Cake Build with a custom NuGet feed server with authentication?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Cake utilizes the `NuGet.exe` for installing tools, addins and the NuGet aliases.

Unless you have a source specified in the `#tool`/`#addin` directives or provided to the NuGet aliases, then `NuGet.exe` will look for `nuget.config` in current path and eventually end up at current users global settings (`%AppData%\NuGet\NuGet.config`).

You have a couple of options, if you don't want to change anything in Cake files or your repository, then you can store your credentials for your user globally and `NuGet.exe` will pick these up example:

```
nuget sources Update -Name [name of source] -Source [uri to your source] -UserName [your username] -Password [your password]
```

*disclaimer some versions of `NuGet.exe` and dotnet CLI have issues with encrypted passwords, an workaround for this is adding the `-StorePasswordInClearText` like this*:

```
nuget sources Update -Name [name of source] -Source [uri to your source] -UserName [your username] -Password [your password] -StorePasswordInClearText
```

Then your credentials are saved in plain text, which works with the drawback that your credentials are saved in **plain text**.

You can also override `nuget.config` settings by specifying a specific source for `#tool`/`#addin` directives and NuGet aliases.

### #tool directive

Below is an example to illustrate providing a source for the `#tool` directive

```
#tool "NUnit.ConsoleRunner"
or
#tool nuget:?package=NUnit.ConsoleRunner&version=3.4.0
```

becomes

```
#tool nuget:[source]?package=NUnit.ConsoleRunner
or
#tool nuget:[source]?package=NUnit.ConsoleRunner&version=3.4.0
```

and i.e. for the official V2 nuget feed

```
#tool nuget:https://www.nuget.org/api/v2?package=NUnit.ConsoleRunner
or
#tool nuget:https://www.nuget.org/api/v2?package=NUnit.ConsoleRunner&version=3.4.0
```

### #addin directive

Below is an example to illustrate providing a source for the `#addin` directive

```
#addin "Cake.Slack"
or
#addin nuget:?package=Cake.Slack&version=0.4.0
```

becomes

```
#addin nuget:[source]?package=Cake.Slack
or
#addin nuget:[source]?package=Cake.Slack&version=0.4.0
```

and i.e. for the official V2 nuget feed

```
#addin nuget:https://www.nuget.org/api/v2?package=Cake.Slack
or
#addin nuget:https://www.nuget.org/api/v2?package=Cake.Slack&version=0.4.0
```

### NuGet aliases

The NuGet [aliases](http://cakebuild.net/dsl/nuget) have commands like [NuGetAddSource](http://cakebuild.net/api/cake.common.tools.nuget/bdfa6572/7443caf1) and [NuGetHasSource](http://cakebuild.net/api/cake.common.tools.nuget/bdfa6572/6fc1af2f) for working directly with sources, these are great if you for example wish to add sources to a CI before a NuGet restore step like below:

```
var source = new {
                Name = EnvironmentVariable("PRIVATE_FEED_NAME"),
                Source = EnvironmentVariable("PRIVATE_FEED_SOURCE"),
                ApiUserName = EnvironmentVariable("PRIVATE_FEED_USERNAME"),
                ApiKey = EnvironmentVariable("PRIVATE_FEED_PASSWORD")
             };

if (!NuGetHasSource(source.SourceUrl))
{
    NuGetAddSource(
        source.Name,
        source.SourceUrl,
        new NuGetSourcesSettings {
            UserName = source.ApiUserName,
            Password = source.ApiKey
        }
    );
}
```

The above will just add sources to your existing `nuget.config`, but you can also override the NuGet source for the [NuGetInstall](http://cakebuild.net/api/cake.common.tools.nuget/bdfa6572/2451be66) & [NuGetRestore](http://cakebuild.net/api/cake.common.tools.nuget/bdfa6572/256fc700) aliases.

#### NuGetInstall

The NuGetInstall alias has overloads that take an [NuGetInstallSettings](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.NuGet.Install/NuGetInstallSettings/) tool settings class which has an [Source](http://cakebuild.net/api/cake.common.tools.nuget.install/babcb33c/8fefefea) property which you can use to override which feeds are used, example:

```
NuGetInstall("MyNugetPackage", new NuGetInstallSettings {
    Source = new []{ "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" }
});
```

#### NuGetRestore

Similarly the NuGetRestore alias has overloads that lets you specify an [NuGetRestoreSettings](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.NuGet.Restore/NuGetRestorer/) which has an [Source](http://cakebuild.net/api/cake.common.tools.nuget.restore/71880157/9d4610d0) property which you can use to override which feeds are used, example:

```
var solutions = GetFiles("./**/*.sln");
// Restore all NuGet packages.
foreach(var solution in solutions)
{
    Information("Restoring {0}", solution);
    NuGetRestore(
        solution,
        new NuGetRestoreSettings {
            Source = new []{ "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" }
        }
    );
}
```

### Conclusion

There's a few ways to address your issue.

Also you can get improved NuGet restore/install performance by specifying a source when you have multiple sources configured on your machine, but the current project only uses official ones as it then *skips* looking thru all configured feeds and goes streight to the *source*.

But if your feed has authentication then you will need to add credentials for those using `nuget.exe` or [NuGetAddSource](http://cakebuild.net/api/cake.common.tools.nuget/bdfa6572/7443caf1) alias.

*Tip for those using [MyGet](https://www.myget.org/), it has [pre-authenticated](http://docs.myget.org/docs/reference/feed-endpoints) url:s you could use without adding a source, but just specifying the Source property for Restore/Install, this is sensitive information so don't store them in your build scripts but rather as i.e. environment variables*.