# Install a CakeBuild AddIn from an NuGet Server with authentification

Tags: nuget, cakebuild

We are using CakeBuild to automate our Xamarin Build and we have written our own AddIn for CakeBuild.

This AddIn is now moved to an new NuGet Feed server which has a username/password authentication to access.

Now Cake is complaining that it can't access this Nuget source. Is there a way to tell CakeBuild how to access (user/password) the Nuget source?

I tried the following solution but I can't get it to work: [How do we authenticate against a secured NuGet server with Cake build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38818190/how-do-we-authenticate-against-a-secured-nuget-server-with-cake-build)

Does someone have a more detail description for that?

Comment: What version of Cake are you using?

Comment: Cake version 0.25.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with Cake Version 0.25.0 we enabled the In-Process NuGet Client by default.  You can see that in the release notes here:

https://github.com/cake-build/cake/releases/tag/v0.25.0

The In-Process NuGet Client doesn't use NuGet.exe, which is a step on the way to getting a version of Cake that works reliably across all OS'es.  However, in doing this, it has meant that at the minute, authenticated NuGet sources are not supported.  There is an issue to track this feature addition here:

https://github.com/cake-build/cake/issues/2028

For now, it is possible to switch back to using NuGet.exe in Cake, rather than the In-Process NuGet Client.  You can find out information about switching this off here:

https://cakebuild.net/docs/fundamentals/configuration

And further information here:

https://cakebuild.net/docs/fundamentals/default-configuration-values

Essentially though you need to do this:

```
cake.exe --nuget_useinprocessclient=false
```

When calling Cake.  You can do this at the command line, as shown here, or via a cake.config file placed in the repository, or by setting an environment variable.